# extjs3.3 calendar

Tags: php, extjs, calendar

i try using  ajax request for extjs calendar. the only problem is  when creating new record .How to send back eventId to the form .I want to test the update record after receiving new record.When i try to update  it send back auto increment internal record instead of return ajax response eventId.
What i do.

```
'eventadd': {
    fn: function (win, rec) {
        win.hide();
        rec.data.IsNew = false;
        rec.data.eventId = 'testing'; // tengok boleh tak bypass
        this.eventStore.add(rec);
        this.showMsg('Event ' + rec.data.Title + ' was added');
        var data;
        reminder = function (data) {
            var remind;
            if (!data) {
                remind = null;
            } else {
                remind = data;
            }
            return remind;
        };
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '../controller/eventController.php',
            params: {
                method: 'create',
                calendarId: rec.data.CalendarId,
                eventTitle: rec.data.Title,
                eventStart: rec.data.StartDate,
                eventEnd: rec.data.EndDate,
                eventIsAllDay: rec.data.IsAllDay,
                eventReminder: rec.data.Reminder,
                eventIsNew: rec.data.IsNew,
                leafId: leafId
            },
            success: function (response, options) {

                var jsonResponse = Ext.decode(response.responseText);


                if (jsonResponse.success == true) {
                    title = systemLabel;

                } else {
                    title = systemErrorLabel;
                }
                Ext.MessageBox.alert(title, jsonResponse.message);
            },
            failure: function (response, options) {
                // critical bug extjs
                var jsonResponse = Ext.decode(response.responseText);

                Ext.MessageBox.alert(systemErrorLabel, jsonResponse.message);
            }
        });
    },
    scope: this
},
```

Response Output.

```
{"success":true,"message":"Record Created","data":{"eventId":13},"eventId":13}
```

When update  the record.the only problem on me is eventId.
FireBug Console Parameter

```
calendarId  1
eventEnd    2011-08-11T01:00:00
eventId 10000
eventIsAllDay   false
eventIsNew  false
eventReminder   
eventStart  2011-08-11T00:00:00
eventTitle  oh update4d
leafId  516
method  update
```

Answer (score 0):

On create, the event window adds an auto-incremented id to the new record only so that it has a unique id in the local data store, before it gets sent to the server. It is the responsibility of the server code generating the response after an add to replace the id with the real database PK. Any subsequent CRUD actions would then use the correct id.

Comment: So where should i changed  code so  the calendar don't take the this.->newId++; instead of take server response request.I tried to send back ajax request data [{ eventId: new id }].But still no changes.can you show me the exact code where response output can be match to internal id ?

Comment: If refresh the page.yes it will correct.I tried to eventStore.reload.But still don't work at all.

Comment: Solve.  i will release the code.but still to refrest the store. it cannot automatically refresh the id